# My Sites filter on StackExchange only shows stackoverflow

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I don't know if it really does what I believe or what I want it to do. But I expect that if I set the My Sites filter I see the question from all the sites that I am subscribed to. But I realized that it was only showing stackoverflow's questions.

What I want is to see all the newest questions from all the websites that I have an account on.  that is what I was expecting when I used the filter. Can someone explain ?

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is to see all the newest questions from all the websites that I have an account on.

Yeah, that's what happens.

Of course, Stack Overflow gets more questions than all the rest combined, so... You're gonna see a lot more SO questions than anything else.

Comment: But I have my accounts opened in different tabs and I dont see the same.I dont see questions from other accounts at all and there are  lots of questions ommited from stackoverflow

Comment: OK, for the difference between stackoverflow's thread and the thread at EtackExchange. It appears that there is a 4 minutes delay in the thread of StackExchange.